# Schema.org for category page that lists articles

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I'm tagging my website with Microdata and questionning myself about tagging article's listing.

On category page I got a a big article which is tagged but I don't know if I should also tagged the listing.

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" itemref="author publisher">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h3 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="/article1" rel="bookmark">article 1/a></h3>
        <link itemprop="sameAs mainEntityOfPage" href=/article1">
    </header>
    <div>
        <a href="/article1"><img width="150" height="150"  itemprop="image" src="image1.jpg" /></a>
        <div class="resume-article-list">bépo bépo bépo … <a href=" /article1" class="more-link">(Lire la suite…)</a></div> </div>
    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2018-03-15T04:48:53+00:00">
        <time itemprop="dateModified" class="updated" datetime="2018-11-14T13:52:00+00:00"></time>
    </footer>
</article>

<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" itemref="author publisher">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h3 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="/article2" rel="bookmark">article 2/a></h3>
        <link itemprop="sameAs mainEntityOfPage" href=/article2">
    </header>
    <div>
        <a href="/article2"><img width="150" height="150"  itemprop="image" src="image1.jpg" /></a>
        <div class="resume-article-list">bépo bépo bépo … <a href=" /article2" class="more-link">(Lire la suite…)</a></div> </div>
    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2018-03-15T04:48:53+00:00">
        <time itemprop="dateModified" class="updated" datetime="2018-11-14T13:52:00+00:00"></time>
   </footer>
</article>
```

Is it correct?

I got a big doubt if `NewsArticle` could be used on resume,
and also if isn't any trouble to used `mainEntityOfPage` as is not the full article?

Answer (score 3):

If you are marking up a list of things that exist on other pages, then Google recommends using ItemList containing just urls. The destination pages should contain the full markup about the entity:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings