# Schema.org product lists versus individual product pages

Tags: schema.org

I have a page that contains a list of products. Each of these products have a page of their own containing more information, some of that information is to be used in the schema as recommended by Google and isn't available on the page.

I'm assuming I should use the Product schema for the individual product pages. But I am not sure which schema I should use for the list of products. There is a suggestion in another question to use listitems with a link to Google ( [Schema.org for category page that lists articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489943/schema-org-for-category-page-that-lists-articles) ). Problem is, that link now redirects to "carousels" and carousels require position numbers, which I'm fairly indifferent about.

Should I use list items and enforce a position for my items?

Answer (score 1):

To begin: required position number in the carousel should not make you worry. This property may be a value, an object or on array, so you can put pretty anything as value for it and your markup remains still valid. But i think position setup is not a rocket science, even if your markup is created manually.

The answer to your question however is very depending on what do you want to achieve with structured data.

Knowing nothing about the nature of your products and your website i would use both of list and product detail pages.

For the list i would take an [OfferCatalog](https://schema.org/OfferCatalog) - this is just an ItemList, but it broadcasts ecommerce signals.

Product detail pages would be then [Offer](https://schema.org/Offer), with the [itemOffered](https://schema.org/itemOffered)-bridge to [Product](https://schema.org/Product).

Comment: It's a bit complicated, as the item this business is offering are courses. This is why I didn't want to go for OfferCatalog over ItemList. This business also sells those courses, but wants to primarily position itself as a school.

Comment: I think - no problem. The subject of the OfferCatalog/Offer can be Service too. And, since Google doesn't allow rich snippets for organization, positioning itself is in any case only possible through own products and services.

Comment: Google does offer rich snippets for courses though. I am using school instead of organization as the organization is by all intents and purposes an educational institution recognized by the org's local government as such.

Comment: I like the [`OfferCatalog`](https://schema.org/OfferCatalog) idea, but won't then Google expect valid `Offer`s inside of it, including the price info? Unless I got it wrong, that contradicts https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel#summary and https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/5820005, according to which a plain [`ItemList`](https://schema.org/ItemList) should be enough

Comment: @aexl you are right, an `Offer` could be a legit child of the chain `OfferCatalog→ItemList→ItemListElement`. But it is not mandatory. And, indeed, `ItemList` could be fully enough. But we are talking about the kind of `ItemList`, which fits more ecommerce needs, as `ItemList` does - and this is `OfferCatalog`.